# Timers accuracy

Tags: android, multithreading, timer, bluetooth

I am using [this library](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-BluetoothSPPLibrary) to establish a connection and data transfer between two android devices. what i want to do is: one phone send the same message every 2 seconds, everytime the receiver reads the message, it starts some work..
I tried doing that with Timers and TimerTasks, but it is not synchronized at all. i get weird different delays.

```
public void onClick(View v){
            new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    bt.send("Start");//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    Log.i("time", "data sent  "+System.nanoTime());
                                        }
                    try {
                        Thread.currentThread();
                        Thread.sleep(50, 0);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    s.playSound();
                    //                      
                }
            }
            , 0, 3000);
```

and also sleep() is not a good way to produce delays, because sometimes its interrupted.
Is there any other way to do that?